# How to select rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't know is it even possible to do without iterating cursors and filling temp tables. I have trouble to select data looking  like this:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|TypeName  | AlarmType | AlarmCount|
+----------+-----------------------+
|Antibody  | 1         | 2         |
|Bacterium | 1         | 2         |
|Bacterium | 3         | 2         |
|CellLine  | 1         | 2         |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

into result like this (there are 3 different AlarmType but 2 are listed):

```
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
|TypeName  | Alarm1| Alarm2| Alarm3|
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
|Antibody  | 2     | 0     | 0     |
|Bacterium | 2     | 0     | 2     |
|CellLine  | 2     | 0     | 0     |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

As you can see, `AlarmCount` is now shown under corresponding `AlarmType` which is now column. If it isn't possible to do it, "you can't do it without cursors" its also a good answer.

[Here is my fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e57d/1)

Comment: Possible through pivoting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in two ways.

use `Conditional Aggregate` to transpose the `AlarmType` to columns and display corresponding `AlarmCount` under each `AlarmType`.

```
SELECT TypeName,
       Max(CASE WHEN AlarmType = 1 THEN AlarmCount ELSE 0 END) Alarm1,
       Max(CASE WHEN AlarmType = 2 THEN AlarmCount ELSE 0 END) Alarm2,
       Max(CASE WHEN AlarmType = 3 THEN AlarmCount ELSE 0 END) Alarm3
FROM   alarms
GROUP  BY TypeName
```

It can be done through `Pivot` also

```
SELECT TypeName,
       Isnull([1], 0) Alarm1,
       Isnull([2], 0) Alarm2,
       Isnull([3], 0) Alarm3
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   alarms) a
       PIVOT (Max(AlarmCount)
             FOR AlarmType IN([1],
                              [2],
                              [3])) piv
```

**Note:** If you are unaware of `AlarmType` column then you might have to employ `Dynamic Pivot`

Answer (score 0):

This is UNION approach:

```
SELECT Alarm_Type_Name, SUM(Alarm1) AS Alarm1, SUM(Alarm2) AS Alarm2, SUM(Alarm3) AS Alarm3 FROM
(
SELECT TypeName AS Alarm_Type_Name, SUM(AlarmCount) AS Alarm1, 0 AS Alarm2, 0 AS Alarm3 FROM ALARM_TEMP
WHERE AlarmType = 1
GROUP BY TypeName, AlarmCount

UNION 

SELECT TypeName AS Alarm_Type_Name, 0 AS Alarm1, SUM(AlarmCount) AS Alarm2, 0 AS Alarm3 FROM ALARM_TEMP
WHERE AlarmType = 2
GROUP BY TypeName, AlarmCount

UNION 

SELECT TypeName AS Alarm_Type_Name, 0 AS Alarm1, 0 AS Alarm2, SUM(AlarmCount) AS Alarm3 FROM ALARM_TEMP
WHERE AlarmType = 3
GROUP BY TypeName, AlarmCount

)a

GROUP BY Alarm_Type_Name
```

Hope this help.